# Redux Thunk Sharing Async Object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

If I have following thunk:

```
function postReq(body) {
  return dispatch =>
    superagent.post("/files")
              .then(response => dispatch(actionCreator(response)));
}
```

How would I share the superagent request object with other parts of my code base? Would I pass it into the actionCreate and put it in the store?

I would like to abort the request on certain Events, that's the reason I am looking for this.

**EDIT**
To give more context to the Problem on hand. When a user uploads a file he has the option to abort the upload. As I am creating the superagent request within a thunk I need to pass the request object on to be able to call `superagent.abort()`.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly you want to share the object an d not the result? Are you not using ES6 async / await for a particular reason?

Comment: Yes I would like to share the Object. I will take a look at async and await. The Project I am working on is using react redux. I thought there should be way to do it this the redux way, but I might be mistaking.

Comment: I can write an answer and show you how to implement the function with async await if you want, it is way more elegant and readable. Maybe you should use MobX and use and observable pattern. If you give me more details it may be easier for me to help you.

Comment: I added additional information and its in the Question description

Comment: are you using any specific library to handle requests? (sorry to ask so many questions but I do really want to give you a good solution :) )

Comment: I using superagent https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/. No worries. I am grateful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all I would like to introduce you some ES6 features which would make your code WAY more readable. Right now you have:

```
function postReq(body) {
  return dispatch =>
    superagent.post("/files")
              .then(response => dispatch(actionCreator(response)));
}
```

first you could use ES6 to make your function more readable in 2 steps:

**Step 1**

Update your action creator to be stored at a cost variable:

```
const postReq = (body) => {
      return dispatch =>
        superagent.post("/files")
                  .then(response => dispatch(actionCreator(response)));
}
```

**Step2**

Your function is returning a function so you can make it shorter and more readable with an implicit return:

```
const postReq = (body) => (dispatch) => {
            superagent.post("/files")
                      .then(response => dispatch(actionCreator(response)));
}
```

Now, answering you could try to do what they expose here:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1461#issuecomment-190165193

Which applied to your case would be something like:

```
const postReq = (body) => (dispatch) => {
       superagent.post("/files")
                  .then(response => dispatch(actionCreator(response)));

      const abort = superagent.abort.bind(superagent)
      return { abort }       
}
```

I have never done this myself but as far as I understand its binding the abort method to a variable which will be returned and executing the function stored there will call the abort method in the postReq context.

Comment: thanks for putting in the effort. Binding the object to `dispatch` by returning is what I was looking for.